# How can I define an Eloquent relationship using MySQL functions?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I'm having trouble defining a relationship in Eloquent.  I have two tables.

The first table contains email domains.  Here is an example:

```
+-------+----------------+-----------+
| ed_id | ed_domain      | ed_isp_id |
+-------+----------------+-----------+
|    17 |                |         6 |
|    13 | aim.com        |         1 |
|    12 | aol.com        |         1 |
+-------+----------------+-----------+
```

The second table contains information about my users, one of the columns being an email address.

I have tried to set this up using...

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Leadgen\Lead', \DB::raw('SUBSTRING_INDEX(l_email, \'@\', -1)'), 'ed_domain');
}
```

What I expected to happen is something like the following:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN email_domains ON SUBSTRING_INDEX(email, '@', -1) = ed_domain
```

What I receive though is a SQL error.

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'leads.SUBSTRING_INDEX(l_email, '@', -1)' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `leads` where `leads`.`SUBSTRING_INDEX(l_email, '@', -1)` in (aol.com))
```

Comment: Laravel relations cover, well, related tables, pairing primary keys with foreign keys, linking to pivot tables. I don't see such relation in the structure you described. Basically, what you need is a function that does a  join. Query Builder might come in handy.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use the standard Laravel relations as they require to have related tables having foreign keys paired to primary keys. What you can do is to do the LeftJoin using query builder and return the users manually.

```
    public function users() {
        return DB::table('users as u')
                ->leftJoin('email_domains as ed', DB::raw('SUBSTRING_INDEX(u.email, \'@\', -1)'), '=', 'ed.ed_domain')
                ->select('u.*');
    }
```

This function will return query builder object so you can do further chaining according to your requirements and finally use `->get()` to have the final result. I have not actually run the code but basically this is what you need to do.